# Log client ip for each request - access log for kestrel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

Is there anyway to log client ips with kestrel hosting? I specified DEBUG log level in app settings, but still it only shows server path being requested, not from whom.

I know client ip can be get from `HttpContext` structure within each api, but what I'd like is just logging it by the framework, so that I can save adding same function in each api.

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[1]
      Connection id "0HL9L7IJ7JLIV" started.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://192.168.1.110:2180/   <====== it logs the server path
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[9]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase[1]
      Request successfully matched the route with name 'default' and template '{controller}/{action}'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action CH.Api.Controllers.HomeController.Index (CH)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method CH.Controllers.HomeController.Index (CH) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      ...
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[9]
      Connection id "0HL9L7IJ7JLIV" completed keep alive response.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 160.2879ms 200 text/plain; charset=utf-8
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv[6]
      Connection id "0HL9L7IJ7JLIV" received FIN.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[10]
      Connection id "0HL9L7IJ7JLIV" disconnecting.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv[7]
      Connection id "0HL9L7IJ7JLIV" sending FIN.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[2]
      Connection id "0HL9L7IJ7JLIV" stopped.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can create a custom middleware that logs each request with just four lines:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress}] | {context.Request.Path}");
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

Output:

```
[127.0.0.1] | /
[127.0.0.1] | /About
[127.0.0.1] | /Post
```

Or replace `context.Request.Path` with `context.Request.GetDisplayUrl()`to see full URL:

```
[127.0.0.1] | http://127.0.0.1:5000/Post?id=1
```

Comment: Ok, I will go the middleware path if there is no way to do it by just turn it on in config file. I mean, like in nginx, you can do access.log by config file.

Comment: I also have this question: How can we turn on web access logs in Kesrel?

Comment: @dfdumaresq There is a thread on implementing it for Kestrel internally but looks like it has low priority: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5894. There is also a custom middleware with more complex logging features: https://github.com/Tratcher/CommonLog

Comment: Does this add much overhead/latency? It looks pretty benign but I don't know what the console.writeline will do in the background